# Solve parity game in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, polynomial-time, game-theory

Is it possible to solve a [parity game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_game) in polynomial time? If yes, how? If no, why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parity games are famously known to be in $NP\cap coNP$, and in fact, in $UP\cap coUP$.
However, there are no polynomial algorithms known for them.

To be more specific, the best algorithms run in time that is polynomial in the number of states $n$, but exponential in the parity index $d$.

The state of the art, as far as I know, is [Jurdzinsky's work here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dcs.warwick.ac.uk%2F~mju%2FPapers%2FJPZ08-SIAMJComp.pdf&ei=KT5pUoL1AoKv4ATP0YCABw&usg=AFQjCNEhR0_j3OX_-J3lhcff7OSiTihmJQ&sig2=q8Uh00bN0ZbgpAmCwWmxtA&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bGE).

Parity games is one of the rare problems we know to be in $NP\cap coNP$, but don't know to be in $P$. Since most other candidates for such languages were eventually shown to be in $P$, it is not unreasonable to believe that a polynomial time algorithm will be found.

Answer (score 8):

The state of the art for solving parity games is now quasipolynomial time. [Here](http://chneukirchen.org/trivium/2017-03-06) are references:

> [Deciding Parity Games in Quasipolynomial Time](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~sanjay/paritygame.pdf) (PDF), by Cristian S. Calude, Sanjay Jain, Bakhadyr Khoussainov, Wei Li, and Frank Stephan.
>
> [A short proof of correctness of the quasi-polynomial time algorithm for parity games](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01953), by Hugo Gimbert and Rasmus Ibsen-Jensen.
>
> [Succinct progress measures for solving parity games](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05051), by Marcin Jurdziński and Ranko Lazić, LICS 2017.

An implementation and comparison with previous approaches is available (classic strategy improvement "wins" on random instances, but gets "slow" on Friedmann’s trap examples):

[An Ordered Approach to Solving Parity Games in Quasi Polynomial Time and Quasi Linear Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01296), by John Fearnley, Sanjay Jain, Sven Schewe, Frank Stephan, Dominik Wojtczak