# what are the basic/typical/common mistakes in P=NP claims?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

the P vs NP problem attracts a lot of attention, not all of it desirable, for a wide variety of reasons. there are many P=NP claims eg on this widely cited list maintained by mathematician Woegeorgi, [P vs NP page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm). also, intermittently there are hot questions on SE sites related to P vs NP (eg recently [2],[3]) below, & there is even a `p-vs-np` tag on both cs.se ([p-vs-np](/questions/tagged/p-vs-np)) & [tcs.se](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-vs-np) sites. the following is intended somewhat as a reference question.

> what are the basic/typical/common mistakes in P=NP claims?

[1] [How not to solve P=NP?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/how-not-to-solve-p-np), cs.se
[2] [P vs NP code exercise, codegolf.se](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24401/so-obviously-p-np)
[3] [Analogs of P vs NP in the history of mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160265/analogues-of-p-vs-np-in-the-history-of-mathematics) MO.se

Comment: To me, this seems like a duplicate of [1]. How would this question be different?

Comment: agreed similar, feel its not a duplicate because the other question mentions abstract/theoretical principles such as "barriers", BGS relativization, natural proofs etc but doesnt mention more specific errors in the numerous attempts such that authors can check against; the code golf question [2] mentions typical errors in its intro (not mentioned in the supposed dup question). ie other is "top-down" vs this is "bottom-up".

Comment: The answers given for [1] are how not to show P!=NP. I thought @vzn was asking specifically about false proofs of P=NP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, people claim to find a polytime algorithm for an NP-hard problem. A couple things could go wrong:

1. The algorithm does not return a correct answer.
2. The algorithm does not run in polytime.

An example of the first mistake is Ted Swart's LP formulations for TSP. They were of poly-size (and so could be solved in polytime with any polytime LP algorithm), but the formulations were not tight. ([More info here.](http://spokutta.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/1311/))

I have [blogged about a particular case of the second mistake](http://farkasdilemma.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/on-false-proofs-of-pnp-or-how-not-to-use-induction/). The short story is that the proof of poly runtime "solved" a recurrence relation incorrectly.